# how to get column name from database in R

Tags: mysql, sql, database, r

I'm using `sqldf` to get some column from table in database, but the result doesn't show the column name, which is I just get the contents.

My code is following as:

```
 z<-sqldf("select (gid, longitude, latitude, acq_date) from kalimantan limit 10" )
```

and the result

```
                                                  row 1   
 (1,112.544000000000000,-2.145000000000000,39448) 2  
 (2,111.617000000000000,-2.720000000000000,39448) 3  
 (3,110.277000000000000,-2.554000000000000,39448) 4  
 (4,117.037000000000010,-0.553000000000000,39449) 5  
 (5,117.583000000000000,-0.462000000000000,39454) 6  
 (6,110.292000000000000,-1.517000000000000,39455) 7  
 (7,111.517000000000000,-2.399000000000000,39455) 8  
 (8,110.285000000000000,-2.660000000000000,39455) 9  
 (9,109.527000000000000,-0.219000000000000,39455) 10
 (10,110.756000000000000,-2.727000000000000,39457)
```

What I need is

```
gid  |     longitude         |          latitude           |  date     
 1      112.544000000000000     -2.145000000000000,39448)    1  
 2      111.617000000000000     -2.720000000000000,39448)    2  
 3      110.277000000000000     -2.554000000000000,39448)    3  
 4      117.037000000000010     -0.553000000000000,39449)    4
 5      117.583000000000000     -0.462000000000000,39454)    5  
 6      110.292000000000000     -1.517000000000000,39455)    6  
 7      111.517000000000000     -2.399000000000000,39455)    7  
 8      110.285000000000000     -2.660000000000000,39455)    8
 9      109.527000000000000     -0.219000000000000,39455)    9 
 10     110.756000000000000     -2.727000000000000,39457)    10
```

Comment: I also get the warning message like this

In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type record (id:2249) in column 0)

Can anyone help me to explain why the warning message appear?

Comment: try: sqldf("select gid, longitude, latitude, acq_date from kalimantan limit 10")

Comment: "postgresqlResultInfo will cause the entire R session crash when there is array columns in the resultset." from https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/issues/detail?id=5

Comment: The SQL statement you mention would only get the contents. To get the column names you would need to access tables that are SQL specific. You should figure out what type of DB you are using and post the question with an SQL tag e.g. How do I get the column names from a specific table in MSSQL/PostgreSQL/MongoDB/etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think the problem is in my db there are geom (I input the contain of db from .shape) if I delete column geom everything back to normal